# "pipenv install tensorflow" stuck on "Locking..."

Tags: python, tensorflow, pipenv

In my virtual environment (created through pipenv), I try running `pipenv install tensorflow`. The following is the output:

```
Installing tensorflow…
Adding tensorflow to Pipfile's [packages]…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (a451a4) out of date, updating to (5ca2ea)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
⠦ Locking...
```

And it remains stuck on `Locking...` for atleast ten minutes, so I decided to kill the installation at that point. So it's stuck on the part where it's adding tensorflow to the Pipfile.lock file. I have python version 3.6.8 (I don't want to upgrade to 3.7 because tensorflow is still not compatible with 3.7 to my knowledge) and I am wondering why it is stuck on the locking portion of the installation. Please help, thanks!

Comment: tensorflow 2 is supported for 3.5 - 3.8

Comment: Oh, I thought tensorflow was still good to use up through 3.7, so is the command for that then pipenv install tensorflow2?

Comment: It would select the right version for you if not specified. The issue is with pipenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `PIPENV`. You will have to update pipenv to master branch and verify that tensorflow == 2.0.0-rc0 can be installed.

You can use this instead
`pipenv run pip install tensorflow`

You can find more on this issue at [GitHub Issues Pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3921)

Comment: Ok cool, just a general question, I am currently in a virtual environment created by pipenv, does running "pipenv run pip install tensorflow" put tensorflow in the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock properly? Or should I do what you first suggested and upgrade pipenv. If I upgrade pipenv, wouldn't I have to remove the current virtual environment?

Comment: No need to remove the current virtual environment.

Comment: Also, if I have pip3, should I run "pip3 install --upgrade pipenv" as opposed to "pip install --upgrade pipenv"? Why are people still using pip for things now that we have pip3 (sorry for all the questions, but you seem to know this well, so I thought I'd ask).

Comment: @jalunceford As per my knowledge it should add.

Comment: Pip operates on any python version available in the context. Your Virtual Environment. While pip3 or pip2 will oprate only on python3 or python2 respectively

Comment: And I was looking at that github link and it seemed like one person preferred just running "pipenv run pip install tensorflow" or "pipenv run pip3 install tensorflow"...is that preferred over upgrading pipenv and then installing tensorflow 2?

Comment: Yes preferred over upgrading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220653/discussion-between-aagam-sheth-and-jalunceford).